Trying to remember a Japanese film about kids who were abandoned by their mother
So, some years back, I remember watching this Japanese film about a young(ish) boy (pre-teen to early teen) and his siblings (two sisters, I think). They lived with the boy's single mum in her apartment until she left and didn't return. (She decided to live with her new boyfriend, but never told him she had kids, and so left them behind in her old apartment to fend for themselves.) I would guess that it's a film from sometime in the 2000s, based on the video quality (which seemed to be digital rather than physical film, if I recall, though don't quote me on that).
I remember a few bits of scenes. Hopefully they'll help jog somebody's memory:

A neighbor comes into the apartment to tell the kids to be quiet, and
they have to pretend that they're just visiting and that the mum is
going to come back to the apartment soon, because the landlady or
landlord doesn't want kids living in their apartment building.
The boy tries to get work at a grocery store or some such, but can't
because he's too young.
They try to avoid getting involved with social services, because that
had happened before and the boy got separated from his siblings for a
while.
I remember finding some of the transitions between scenes to be a bit
weird - they'd use images of trees and other such things between
scenes, but not in a montage-ish way. More like "scene - cut to
single (unrelated) image of a tree and pause for a moment - cut to
next (unrelated) scene." (Maybe I'd have a different feeling about it now,
if I saw it again, but I remember feeling at the time like it was
just weird and not very effective.)
I think the last scene (or one of the scenes towards the end, at
least) was of the kids sitting silently next to each other as they
rode a bullet train. (Possibly after having to bury somebody.)

I'm not sure I'd actually want to watch the movie again, but it's bugging me that I can't remember the title.

I think the film is the award-winning Nobody Knows (Daremo Shiranai) (2004) by writer-director Hirokazu Koreeda. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_Knows_%282004_film%29
The film begins with a low-income mother (played by singer-actress YOU) smuggling most of her children secretly into a new apartment, notably by hiding one of them in a travel suitcase. After she abandons them, the children struggle to make ends meet. One boy seeks help from their father, and works part time. [Edited for spoilers] I can confirm that after burying a body at the airport, around 2:07:00 of the 2:20:00 runtime of the film, there is a scene where two of the children ride a train home. 
Here's a handy Youtube of the movie's closing song, also depicting that train ride: 



Fantastic film! Very troubling. I saw it when it came to DVD in 2005 and was so upset I've never brought myself to see it again, only now going back and digging it up to confirm this answer. Yet as soon as I started reading your description I was sure it had to be Nobody Knows. The film sticks with people. Up there with Grave of the Fireflies (Hotaru no Haka) (1988) in terms of difficulty. 

I'm not sure I'd actually want to watch the movie again

Extremely understandable. Hard to recommend to anyone without warning them they'll cry in a cold bathtub after! 

"Fantastic film" Oh, and then some. Nice answer (and question!)
